# GSAP: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, draggable, gsap

Im trying to implement the code from this [codepen](https://codepen.io/snorkltv/pen/WNoJPor) into a nuxtjs project and when I run it I get this error
`Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`
and here's what I have in my vue file:

```html
<template>
  <div class="gallery">
    <img src="@/assets/images/before.png" />
    <img class="clipped" src="@/assets/images/after.png" />
    <div class="dragger"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Draggable from '../libraries/gsap/Draggable'
import { gsap } from '../libraries/gsap'

gsap.registerPlugin(Draggable)

export default {
  mounted() {
    gsap.to('.gallery', { autoAlpha: 1 })
    gsap.set('.dragger', { x: 320 })
    Draggable.create('.dragger', {
      type: 'x',
      bounds: '.gallery',
      onDrag: () => {
      const x = 640 - gsap.getProperty(this.target, 'x')
      gsap.set('.clipped', { clipPath: `inset(0px ${x}px 0px 0px)` })
      },
    })
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are your sure the error is coming from here?

Comment: I tried commenting that part of code inside mounted() and I still get that error

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution to this? I'm getting the same error.